# How to deal with <FE><FF> in what should be valid utf-8? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, pdftotext

I am using `pdftotext` with options "-enc utf-8 -htmlmeta -raw" and passing that into a python script, which is parsing the output.  (Please read on even if you're unfamiliar with pdftotext, since that may not be relevant.)

For some of the pdf's that we are processing, pdftotext is outputting metadata that looks like this:

```
<meta name="CreationDate" content="<FE><FF>">
```

In python, I am doing this (basically):

```
attrib[name] = content.decode('utf-8')
```

where `content` is that `<FE><FF>` string in the above piece of metadata. Python raises an exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: unexpected code byte
```

At this point, I am unsure if the problem is the PDF itself, or the output from pdftotext, or Python's way of interpreting utf-8.

I have googled and not found anything conclusive.

Essentially, I would expect `pdftotext -enc utf-8` to *only* output valid utf-8. And I would expect Python to understand how to deal with that utf-8 when decoding. Is there some part of this that I am missing?

I would appreciate any help in understanding why this is occurring, and help with a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `0xFE 0xFF` is the UTF-16 big-endian byte order marker. It indicates the character encoding of the file, which means Python is seeing it as UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First, instead of using `content.decode('utf-8')`, use:

```
content.decode('utf-8-sig')
```

This will automatically remove the BOM (if one is present).

Second, it looks like `pdftotext` is outputting a UTF-16 BOM, not a UTF-8 one. The UTF-8 BOM is '\xEF\xBB\xBF'. You'll need to figure out why you're getting UTF-16, or change your script to decode from UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I did try utf-8-sig already, to no avail.

The strange thing is that we are processing approximately 100k PDFs and only about 500 of them seem to have this issue. And every time it's the exact same character "0xfe". There is no other issue with decoding as utf-8, the expected output.

Could there be any harm in using utf-16? Or is a cleaner approach to simply remove this character sequence before called content.decode()? Thanks!

Comment: @jeffp: Hmm, if it's inconsistent, possibly the bytes are coming from the PDF itself -- in which case, you can either switch to UTF-16 to mask the problem or manually check for and strip out the extraneous BOM yourself. Perhaps `try` utf-8-sig and fallback to UTF-16 if an exception is raised?

Comment: I tried a simple test where I try utf-16 and I get a different error instead: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 7804: truncated data"

Thank for you at least validating that it is inconsistent.

I think I will go with striping those bytes.

Comment: I could always do this too: content.decode('utf-8','ignore')

It doesn't seem like a clean approach though.

Comment: @jeffp: Yep, the joy of parsing real-world data :-) There isn't really a "best answer" for this one, since it seems some of the data will get corrupted one way or another. I guess the best option is whichever yields the best results on your actual data set.